# How to change action bar background on click of "Search" menu?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have gone through the Search Interface tutorial on Android Developers site and implemented successfully too.

The only thing that I haven't been able to achieve is to change the Actionbar background on click of search menu and to revert it back on clicking the "Back" button?

Below is a screenshot from Gmail app. The normal actionbar looks like this.

[image]

And when you click on Search menu it changes to one like below without changing the activity.

[image]

I want to achieve this functionality. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `FrameLayout` is created in the Gmail application which contains two views:

- `Toolbar` - first red Toolbar which is available in public API
- `MaterialSearchActionView` which contains three views

  - `ImageView` - with back arrow
  - `EditText`
  - `ImageView` - with "x" / "microphone"

The second view is not available in public API.

I think that the idea is easy. When you open your `Activity` the second view is `GONE` and when you press **Search icon** it is shown. There is no way to get `MaterialSearchActionView` so you have to create your own View which contains these controls.

I create small example how to do this:

DoubleActionBarActivity.class:

```
public class DoubleActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    Toolbar searchToolbar;
    boolean isSearch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_double_toolbar);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        searchToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
        prepareActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    private void prepareActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(isSearch ? android.R.color.darker_gray : android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(isSearch ? R.menu.search_for_second_toolbar : R.menu.search_item_only, menu);
        if (isSearch) {
            final SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

            search.setIconified(false);
            search.setQueryHint("search");
            search.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onClose() {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.action_search:{
                isSearch = true;
                searchToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                prepareActionBar(searchToolbar);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;
            }
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(isSearch){
                    isSearch = false;
                    prepareActionBar(toolbar);
                    searchToolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_with_double_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

search_for_second_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

search_item_only.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="search"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom" ></item>
</menu>
```

Additionally you can look on this library

https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch

It can be interesting for you.

Comment: Hi Konrad, It solves the problem big time. Thanks for your time digging into the API.

Comment: Also thanks for that link. Gonna need it in another application!